# Rails index list a variable does change during looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set a button for each Client in an index list that will take you to that Client's Location.

This is my code:

```
  <% Client.active.find_each do |client| %>
<tr>
<td><strong><%= link_to client.client_name, client_path(client) %></strong></td>
<td><%= client.locname %></td>
<td><%= client.phone1 %></td>
<td><%= client.fax %></td>
<td><%= client.worequests.notcompl.count %></td>
<td><%= client.workorders.count %></td>
<td><%= client.contacts.count %></td>
  <% location = Location.where('locname' == client.locname).first.id %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Tree', location_url(location), :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-primary' %></td>
  <% if current_user.has_role? :admin or current_user.has_role? :super %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_client_path(client), :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-success' %></td>
  <% else %>
    <td></td>
  <% end %>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

But, the link is always to location/13 - which is from the first location.where lookup.

Why doesn't each Client's Tree button point to their location?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your problem:

```
Location.where('locname' == client.locname)
```

should be

```
Location.where(:locname => client.locname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause is evaluating to true no matter what.  I think you want:

```
Location.where('locname=?', client.locname).first.id
```